# Multithreaded embedded Python. Is this right?

Tags: python, c++, concurrency, cpython, python-embedding

I'm writing a C++ application in which I want to run multiple Python scripts concurrently using embedded Python 3.7. The scripts should be run independently of each other, so they should not share any variables.

I think I finally figured it out. But I just want to be sure if this is the right way. Can anyone confirm if this code does not have any hidden problems or if there is a better way to solve the problem?

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

PyThreadState *threadState;

void longRunningFunction () {
    PyThreadState *t = PyEval_SaveThread();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    PyEval_RestoreThread(t);
}

void run () {
    // Prepare
    PyEval_RestoreThread(threadState);
    PyThreadState *t = Py_NewInterpreter();

    // Execute Python code
    // For simplicity of the example, this is mixed with C++ code.
    // Usually you would have the for loop and the call
    // to longRunningFunction() in Python code.
    PyRun_SimpleString("x = 0");
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        PyRun_SimpleString("x += 1; print(x, flush=True)");
        longRunningFunction();
    }

    // Clean up
    Py_EndInterpreter(t);
    PyThreadState_Swap(threadState);
    PyEval_SaveThread();
}

#define THREAD_COUNT 3

int main () {
    // Initialize Python
    Py_Initialize();
    threadState = PyEval_SaveThread();

    // Start threads
    std::thread thread[THREAD_COUNT];
    for (int i=0; i<THREAD_COUNT; i++) {
        thread[i] = std::thread(run);
    }

    // Wait for threads to finish
    for (int i=0; i<THREAD_COUNT; i++) {
        thread[i].join();
    }

    // Finalize Python
    Py_Finalize();
}
```

Compile code:

```
g++ main.cpp "-IC:/Program Files/Python37_64/include" "-LC:/Program Files/Python37_64/libs" -lpython37 -o main.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler, safer and more performant (in case of more than one Python thread) to run Python scripts in another process. Due to the global interpreter lock your Python threads cannot run in parallel inside one process. This way it is also easier to interrupt and terminate those Python processes without making a mess out of your process.

Comment: In my case the scripts need to communicate with an other part of the process. So I could run the scripts in a different process, but then I'll have to invent some communication protocol, and it won't be simpler anymore.